# How to construct a historic Date (year 0-100) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to construct a `Date` from a `year`, `month`, `day` tuple, however I'd like to be able to construct "historic" dates as well. For instance Nero's birthday: 15 December 37. The straightforward implementation

```js
function constructDate(year, month, day) {
  return new Date(year, month-1, day);
}
```

however returns `Wed Dec 15 1937 00:00:00 GMT+0100` for `constructDate(37, 12, 15)`, because of the constructor's magic to treat years in the range 0-100 as 1900-2000. I'm trying to find a good way to bypass this behavior.

A naive approach would be to construct a temporary date with an arbitrary year, and then call `setFullYear()` to get the actual target date. However, I have a few concerns:

- Trying to do so for Nero's birthday in Firefox, returns `Tue Dec 15 0037 00:00:00 GMT+0053`. What has happened to the time zone offset there?
- I'm not sure if there are subtleties e.g. when constructing February 29. If the target year is a leapyear, but the temporary year isn't, i.e., doesn't have February 29, am I in trouble?
- Internally the construction from year/month/day requires the computation of the underlying Unix epoch timestamp. With the `setFullYear()` work-around there would be two timestamp computations, one of them all in vain.

Is there a way to construct such a `Date` without a temporary / computing the timestamp twice internally?

Comment: Your "naive" approach is indeed what is recommended by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Two_digit_years_map_to_1900_%E2%80%93_1999)...

Comment: `Date`s are computed using [the proleptic Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar). When you start using that calendar for dates before that calendar was instituted (October of 1582), things get weird.

Comment: "Better" and "best" are opinions. Setting a date in a year after 1900 that shares the "leapness" of the target year and then using `setFullYear` should be good enough for almost every situation.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Computing something twice that only needs to be computed once isn't very opinionated in terms of "better". But okay, then this is just a mess. What the MDN suggest is somewhat dangerous: Using year=0 to construct the temporary is a bug, because the year 1900 wasn't a leap year, whereas 0 was. Code making this mistake couldn't construct February 29 in the year 0. I still don't understand the `GMT+0053` though (it jumps between 1893 and 1894), so there is a difference e.g. for using the year 1000 vs 2000 as a temporary.

Comment: *setFullYear* can set all parts at once: `d.setFullYear(37,12,15)` so leap years are handled. Timezones didn't exists for such dates, nor did leap years so don't get too precious about that. You're extrapolating the Gregorian calendar back to about 1500 years before it existed. The proposed new [*Temporal* object](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/index.html) should fix these types of issue.